# Google api library doesn't throw a "invalid_client" when authorize with invalid client_id [C#]

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm working with google api library C# and when I authorize with invalid client id, the page with 401 error opens in my browser but my program freezes and does nothing. It doesn't trow any exceptions. But if I authorize with valid client id and invalid client secret, it throws the "invalid_client" exception. What is wrong and how to fix it?

```
try
{
var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "client_id",
                        ClientSecret = client_secret
                    },
                    new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
                    Environment.UserName,
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(file_store)).Result;
service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = credential });
}
catch(Exception)
{
    return false;
}
```

The idea was to check the validity of the client id and client secret. If we authorize with such client id and client secret and get an error, they are invalid and we ask the user to check the entered data

UDP:
I found that Status of GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync doesn't change over time and stays "WaitingForActivation"

Comment: Did you create installed application credentials on google cloud console?

Comment: Yes, i did. If  client id and client secret are both valid, the program works fine

Comment: Sorry I think i miss understood your question.  Check my answer see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have now doesn't actually do anything your just loading the service object.  Its not going to fail until you attempt to use it.

making a call to the api would cause it to fail, requesting an access token would also cause it to fail if you have given it an invalid client id, or if the refresh token has expired.

```
var accessToken = await credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did't work. But I found that the Status of GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync doesn't change. It stays "WaitingForActivation"

Comment: What type of app is this?  This a console application? Your code is the same as mine.  Did you remember to delete the file in file_store or change Environment.UserName to something else?